# Is there a better way to decode html directly on Android?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, html-entities, html-encode

I've got encoded html where even tags are encoded into html entities

```
Some &lt;b&gt; bold &lt;/b&gt; text
```

I'd like to display this as a spanned string in `TextView`, however the only way to do it is using `Html.fromHtml()` twice

```
val decoded = Html.fromHtml("").toString() // Some <b>bold</b> text
val spanned = Html.fromHtml(decoded)
```

Is there cleaner way to do this?

Comment: In Strings.xml? And is that Kotlin you are using?

Comment: obviously `"Some &lt;b&gt; bold &lt;/b&gt; text"` doesn't contains html tags when `"Some <b> bold </b> text"` does

Comment: The encoded string is part of network response, that's the reason why it's in this format. Language is not that important for the question

Comment: `val spannable = Html.fromHtml(myHTML.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">"));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use cdata:

```
<string name="string"><![CDATA[Some <b>bold</b> text]]></string>
```

Then you just pass the text directly into HTML.fromHtml (remember that API 24 has a new call, so you have to take that into consideration)